# setting server software variable in Golang net/http

Tags: apache, go

I'm benchmarking my application with `ab -c 100 -n 10000 http://{your ip}:8000/`, everything is fine, but being obsessive as I am, I found that while describing the server, it came back with

```
Server Software:        
Server Hostname:        localhost
Server Port:            1337

Document Path:          /
Document Length:        19 bytes
```

How do I set the Server Software variable? I can't live with that empty field right there.

Comment: PS: Use wrk - https://github.com/wg/wrk - to benchmark.

Comment: @elithrar: `./wrk wrk -t12 -c400 -d30s http://127.0.0.1:1337/`
Segmentation fault (core dumped) :)

Answer (score 1):

Set a `Server` header. See [RFC-2616 section 14.38](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.38) and [ResponseWriter](http://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#ResponseWriter).Header.

```
w.Header().Set("Server", "MyServer")
```

Comment: Like `w.Header().Set("Server:", "MyServer")`? This doesn't work. still empty field. Also tried wo the ":" in the key.

Comment: The documentation for ab (http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/programs/ab.html) confirms that it's based on the Server header. Check that it's actually in your server's response.

Comment: @DervinThunk `w.Header().Set("Server", "MyServer")`, no `:`

Comment: Thanks. Looks like you're right. My server does return the server (if I use Firefox Poster, for example), but not `ab`. I'm sure it's something silly I'm doing wrong.